# How to change the properties of a textbox in C#?

Tags: c#

I am a beginning C# noob and I am making my own wordpad/document creator, and I want to change the property of a textbox via the code. What I am trying to do is have three buttons: Left, Center, and Right, and I am trying to make them so that they change the "TextAlign" property, when they are clicked on. Does anyone have some suggestions? I hove done some research and turned up with nothing.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the properties? `textBox1.TextAlign = TextAlign.Center`?

Comment: Please let us know if you are using wpf or forms

Comment: Give a name to your `TextBox` such as `tbContent` and then add three buttons, again name them appropriately such as `tbAlignRight`, `tbAlignCenter` and `tbAlignLeft`.

Comment: What research did you do? To turn up absolutely _nothing_ is remarkable. What code do you have so far? What about it isn't working for you? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a name to your TextBox such as `tbContent` and then add three buttons, again name them appropriately such as `btnAlignRight`, `btnAlignCenter` and `btnAlignLeft`.

Now, go to your .cs file and then Add event handlers for your three buttons through the designer. Shortcut: Just double click on the buttons one by one when in the designer, it will automatically generate and register the `Click` EventHandler for that button.

And then add the code provided by badkip in the appropriate EventHandler